# How to write a GetEnumerator for Pre-order, Postorder, In-order traversal?

Tags: c#, foreach, tree

I have written 3 methods for my BST:

1. PreOrder();
2. PostOrder();
3. InOrder();

They are all recursive methods, and I have to Print the value inside the method, but what i want is to return the value and print it outside of these method.
I have written a GetEnumerator() for InOrder, but the problem is that I need all tree methods.
one way is to add values to an array and return the array, but that is not good for performance, because we added an array to our code.
**Edit:How can i have GetEnumerator for all my hree methods?**

```
public void PreOrder(BinaryTreeNode<T> node)
{
    if (node != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(node.Value.ToString());
        PreOrder(node.Left);
        PreOrder(node.Right);
    }
}

public void PostOrder(BinaryTreeNode<T> node)
{
    if (node != null)
    {
        PostOrder(node.Left);
        PostOrder(node.Right);
        MessageBox.Show(node.Value.ToString());
    }
}

public void InOrder(BinaryTreeNode<T> node)
{
    if (node != null)
    {
        InOrder(node.Left);
        MessageBox.Show(node.Value.ToString());
        InOrder(node.Right);
    }
}
```

GetEnumerator inside BinaryTreeNode class.

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    if (Left != null)
    {
        foreach (var v in Left)
        {
            yield return v;
        }
    }

    yield return Value;

    if (Right != null)
    {
        foreach (var v in Right)
        {
            yield return v;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking. I'm struggling to find the question.

Comment: Is your question how to support multiple enumerators on the same collection?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko look at %00 - Internal Server Error comment.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError i wanted to use yield return for all tree methods instead of MessageBox.Show(), how can i modify the code to do such. it is not the duplicate of that link. maybe still doesn't understand what i want?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko did you understand the question? look at edit and coments.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from having multiple methods that all  use yield and return an IEnumerator<T>. Only one can be called GetEnumerator(), but for others you can use them e.g. like so: `foreach someElement in myObject.PreOrderEnum()`... where PreOrderEnum would return the IEnumerator<T> instance for enumerating nodes in pre-order.

Comment: Your "non-recursive" implementation of `GetEnumerator` is in fact recursive...

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I should known all of the answer in your duplicate link? and your answer in comment is not enough. there must be an overloaded method with sending root as parameter. look at the answer, it is too diffirent from what is in duplicate link.

Comment: @Riddle No, the method doesn't need to be overloaded.  No, you don't need to have multiple methods for each type of traversal.  That's just one option, of many possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd implement it this way:

```
public class BinaryTree<T>{
    BinaryTreeNode<T> root;

    #Your code....

    public IEnumerable<BinaryTreeNode<T>> PreOrder(){
        return DoPreorder(root);
    }

    public IEnumerable<BinaryTreeNode<T>> PostOrder(){
        return DoPostOrder(root);
    }

    public IEnumerable<BinaryTreeNode<T>> InOrder(){
        return DoInOrder(root);
    }

    private IEnumerable<BinaryTreeNode<T>> DoPreorder(BinaryTreeNode<T> node){
        if(node != null){
            yield return node;
        }
        else{
            yield break;
        }

        foreach(var leftNode in DoPreorder(node.Left)){
            yield return leftNode;
        }

        foreach(var rightNode in DoPreorder(node.Right)){
            yield return rightNode;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<BinaryTreeNode<T>> DoPostOrder(BinaryTreeNode<T> node){
        if(node == null){
            yield break;
        }

        if(node.Left != null){
            foreach(var leftNode in DoPostOrder(node.Left)){
                yield return leftNode;
            }
        }

        if(node.Right != null){
            foreach(var rightNode in DoPostOrder(node.Right)){
                yield return rightNode;
            }
        }

        yield return node;
    }

    private IEnumerable<BinaryTreeNode<T>> DoInOrder(BinaryTreeNode<T> node){
        if(node == null){
            yield break;
        }

        if(node.Left != null){
            foreach(var leftNode in DoInOrder(node.Left)){
                yield return leftNode;
            }
        }

        yield return node;

        if(node.Right != null){
            foreach(var rightNode in DoInOrder(node.Right)){
                yield return rightNode;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now if you need to print the values of the nodes in PreOrder, you'd just need to do this:

```
var tree = GetYourTree();

foreach(var node in tree.PreOrder()){
    Console.WriteLine(node.Value);
}
```

Another approach would be to implement Preorder; PostOder and InOrder as properties.

As one way of implementing GetEnumerator, I suggest you to return a Dictionary>> containing a string like "preorder", "postorder" and "inorder" as keys and IEnumerable> as the values you can get calling the previous implemented methods.

Hope it helps,

Comment: @Riddle Remove it and see for yourself.  You'd just get a Null Reference Exception when you ran the code.